# How to query with massive selection arguments?

Tags: android, sqlite

I meet a situation that I can workaround but is seeking a better way to do. It is:

- I have 8,000+ songs in an Android device. That is, Android's Audio.Media has 8,000+ rows.
- That is, I have an array with 2,000 paths, and I need to query the database for other columns of corresponded files.

By now I use `resolver.query(URI, "_data IN (?,?,?........,?)", selectionArgs, null);`

But if the `?` is too many like 600 or more, the query will fail since the WHERE clause becomes too long.

So I divide 2,000 paths into four parts, query each and save information needed in other place. With four times query, I can get the result. But this consumes lots of memory, and if I can do it by one query, it will be faster than 4.

Does anyone has better way to do this? Thank you!